# loading external page into div through link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use the following code to load an external page into a div:

```
$("a.btn").click(function(){
    $("div#cart_load").load("*url_here*");
});
```

The problem is, I have multiple links (a.btn) in a page; each with different URL (e.g. http://myurl.com/product/ID) corresponding to different product.

How do I make the load function to automatically get the URL from each link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `href` property of the anchor you're cliking on, like this:

```
$("a.btn").click(function(e) {
  $("#cart_load").load(this.href);
  e.preventDefault(); //stop the browser from following the link
});
```

Comment: Minor overlook but it should prevent the default behavior too